# Getting started with java web applications

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web-development-server

this is my first question on stack so if i missed tag or did something wrong please have understanding. 
I would like to start building web applications (or web services). 
I have following knowledge:
Java programming more than basic but dont think i m really intermediate
Html basics
Css basics
I started trying java spring, and although it has a lot of small piece tutorials which i understand when looking the code, i still have no idea how would i build my own web application

My question would be: how to dive into this kind of development? 
Are there any good tutorials that show builsing a fully intereactive app or something simmilar because i feel like running through cornfield right now, and stumbling on different parts of knowledge that is partialy useful to me..
I would be really gratefull on any tips on what steps to take and what to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through guides on Spring's site https://spring.io/.
For each term that is not familiar, you can find all the documentation written by the Spring team.
Also it is good for you to start learning Hibernate at the same time.
There are good video tutorials but I prefer books and articles, for example: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html